# How to extract images from webm video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, webm, libvpx

I need to extract a set of images from a webm video using ffmpeg (version 0.9.2). 
I currently use this script:

```
./ffmpeg -i video.webm -r 1 -f image2 image-%04d.jpg
```

but I have this error

```
ffmpeg version 0.9.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 23 2013 12:18:47 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-everything --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avfilter --disable-avdevice --enable-libvpx --enable-protocol=file --enable-encoder=mjpeg --enable-encoder=libvpx --enable-decoder=libvpx --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-muxer=webm --enable-muxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mjpeg --enable-muxer=avi --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=avi
  libavutil    51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
  libavcodec   53. 42. 4 / 53. 42. 4
  libavformat  53. 24. 2 / 53. 24. 2
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
/home/username/Desktop/out.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I found that in ffmpeg there isn't a webm demuxer and you can check it typing

```
./configuration --list-demuxers
```

So I'm asking why ffmpeg do not support a webm demuxer which is used by libvpx (used for example in youtube by Google) .

It sounds strange... doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

First, ffmpeg version 0.9.2 is an old version.

And in any case you may found ffmpeg build in which webm is not built-in.

Support for webm come from [libvpx](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/) and `./configure` ffmpeg with `--enable-libvpx`.